# Symfony2: Something like a Role Provider?

Tags: symfony, roles

In my web application, I want my user's to be able to create roles and add users to them dynamically. The only thing I imagine, is to edit the security.yml every time, but this can't be the best solution, can it? It would be very nice, if there is something like a User Provider for roles, so I can define one which loads the roles from a database (doctrine).

Thanks for your help, hice3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, you should want to add a role Entity to your model Hice.

You have to know that Symfony2 provides support for dynamic roles too. You have a `getRoles()` method in the [Symfony2 User spec in the API Doc](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html), that your User entity should implement, that forces him to return Roles. These roles must either implement the [role interface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/RoleInterface.html) that specifies a `getRole()` method that returns, most usually, the role name itself.

You can then add the newly created role directly to your user role list that the `getRoles()` user method will then return.

Here is an example using annotations :
First role class

```
/**
 * Role class
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="userRoles")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

And the User class

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_roles")
     */
    private $userRoles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userRoles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->userRoles->toArray();
    }
```

I've skipped imports and methods to simplify the approach.

EDIT : There is something to know about serialization too. As [Sharom](https://github.com/Sharom) [commented on github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3691#issuecomment-9831914), you musn't serialize users in roles neither roles in users. Just read his post and I think you'll understand :)

Comment: Oh Huston, we have a problem! The script throws a FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object in E:\[...]\MainBundle\Entity\User.php line 138

Comment: Sorry Hice, I forgot one thing about roles / users and serialization. I added them in my post.